# Using ssh tunnel to RDP into internal network

Tags: ssh, rdp, ssh-tunnel

I'm a newbie to tunneling and can't figure this one out.  I have an externally available computer, let's call it example.com, which is Unix.  In its internal network there is a Windows machine I want to access, with an internal ip, let's use 192.168.1.144.  I need to tunnel into example.com in order to RDP into 192.168.1.144. How can I achieve this?

Comment: SSH tunnel. There's tons of guides on how to use one.

Comment: Yes, I know and have read them, however all of the ones I have read assume that the tunnel is the computer that you want to access. I want to access a computer inside the tunnel's network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use SSH tunnelling, like Nathan C said in his comment. The guides assume you're tunnelling to the computer you're connecting to, but only because those guides use 'localhost' as the foreign host name. Try something like this from your home machine:

```
ssh -Nf user@example.com -L 8080:192.168.1.144:[RDP-port]
```

I'm not sure what the port number is for RDP, so I had to leave that unreplaced. Once you execute this command (with the proper port number for "RDP-port"), it should background and you should be able to RDP to "localhost:8080" from your home machine and end up talking to the Windows machine on the inside.